# Reorder byte order for an array of 24-bit bytes using endian manipulations in arduino/c/c++?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a 24-bit array:

```
uint32_t rgbdata[] = { 0x00ff00 0xff0000 0x0000ff ...... }
```

Let's say the above data is in RGB order and I want GRB order

```
uint32_t grbdata[] = { 0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff ...... }
```

Without using loops, is there a quick endian manipulation way to do a certain byte order? Speed is of utmost importance in this case.

Comment: 24 bits in a uint16_t?  did you compile that?  g++ on lubuntu reports  "error: narrowing conversion of ‘16711680’ from ‘int’ to ‘uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]"

Comment: You might consider an array of uint32_t to hold each 24 bit value, then review ntoh() and hton() for ideas on how they work ...

Comment: Sorry, they are uint32_t array. Still a noob regarding endian operations. I will try to use ntohl() or htonl()

Comment: I mentioned ntohl() and htonl() because they do 'endian' fixes for 32 and 64 bit integers for internet purposes (net-to-host, host-to-net).  I suggested that you 'look' at those implementations for ideas, but they probably won't work for 24 bit numbers.    Consider writing a class, perhaps uint24_t, to provide your needs, and build the 'endian manipulation' routines into the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial example of a uint24_t that you might port to your tools (I don't know the 'current' arduino's tool set)

```
// Note: compile with -std=c++17 for the using comma list
//       or remove these and put the "std::" into code
#include <algorithm>
using std::swap;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::hex, std::dec, std::cin; // c++17

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string; // c++17

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;


class Uint24_t
{
public:
   Uint24_t() : data {0,0,0}
      {
         cout << "\n  sizeof(Uint24_t)= " << sizeof(Uint24_t) // reports 3 bytes
              << " bytes, * 8= " << (sizeof(Uint24_t) * 8) << " bits." << endl;
      }

   Uint24_t(uint32_t initVal) : data {0,0,0}
      {
         data[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>((initVal >>  0) & 0xff); // lsbyte
         data[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>((initVal >>  8) & 0xff); //
         data[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>((initVal >> 16) & 0xff); // msbyte
         cout << "\n  sizeof(Uint24_t)= " << sizeof(Uint24_t) // reports 3 bytes
              << " bytes, * 8= " << (sizeof(Uint24_t) * 8) << " bits." << endl;
      }

   ~Uint24_t() = default;

   std::string show() {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "  show(): "
         << static_cast<char>(data[2]) << "."
         << static_cast<char>(data[1]) << "."
         << static_cast<char>(data[0]);
      return ss.str();
   }

   std::string dump() {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "  dump(): " << hex
         << static_cast<int>(data[2]) << "."
         << static_cast<int>(data[1]) << "."
         << static_cast<int>(data[0]);
      return ss.str();
   }

   void swap0_2() { swap(data[0], data[2]); }


private:
   uint8_t  data[3]; // 3 uint8_t 's
};



class T976_t // ctor and dtor compiler provided defaults
{
public:
   int operator()() { return exec(); } // functor entry

private: // methods

   int exec()
      {
         Uint24_t  u24(('c' << 16) +  // msbyte
                       ('b' <<  8) +
                       ('a' <<  0));

         cout << "\n  sizeof(u24) = " << sizeof(u24) << " bytes"
              << "\n  " << u24.show()
              << "\n  " << u24.dump() << std::endl;

         u24.swap0_2(); // swapping lsByte and msByte

         cout << "\n  sizeof(u24) = " << sizeof(u24) << " bytes"
              << "\n  " << u24.show()
              << "\n  " << u24.dump() << std::endl;

         return 0;
      }



}; // class T976_t


int main(int , char**) { return T976_t()(); } // call functor
```

Typical output:

```
sizeof(Uint24_t)= 3 bytes, * 8= 24 bits.

  sizeof(u24) = 3 bytes
    show(): c.b.a
    dump(): 63.62.61

  sizeof(u24) = 3 bytes
    show(): a.b.c
    dump(): 61.62.63
```